# Is it possible to create constants that are native to IntelliJ (not the program being developed) for use in the Evaluate Expression dialog?

Tags: intellij-idea, constants, evaluate

What I want to do is almost certainly an abuse of the IDE, but it seems like a useful one.
I have a need to create test scripts for a handful of API endpoints. These endpoints often have inputs that are either enums or derived from enums (by concatenation, e.g.)

To generate a set of test inputs, I'm using SQL: cross-joins of subselects consisting of a bunch of literal values. In some cases, these lists of values for a given enum can be quite long.

I've discovered that I can use 'evaluate expression' to generate these subselects automatically:

```
Arrays.asList(Enum.values()).map(Enum::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(
    "' UNION ALL SELECT '", 
    "(SELECT '", 
    "') as enums"));
```

What I'm wondering is, is there a way within IntelliJ to set a constant that is accessible to this dialog, so that I could instead do something like:

```
Arrays.asList(Enum.values()).map(Enum::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(
    MYSQL_SUBSELECT_DELIM, 
    MYSQL_SUBSELECT_PREFIX, 
    MYSQL_SUBSELECT_SUFFIX);
```

It would make this process much more repeatable.

Comment: Have you already considered IntelliJ's live templates? That's the feature that allows one to type `sout` and have it replaced with System.out.println. You can define your own which may help you with some of the boiler-plate of what you're writing.

Comment: *chuckle* This may get confusing, we both go by the name of 'Iain'. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible between debug sessions, but within one session you can use labels for required string objects and then reference them in the evaluate dialog using `name_DebugLabel`:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/examining-suspended-program.html#use-labels